# How to make button stay in one position in a list

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a todo list and was creating a delete button to the side of each task. How can I make the delete buttons appear to the right of each list item?

**Edit:** I managed to figure it out.  It was actually more simple than I expected.  I just used "right: 20px;" under the list tag.

```js
$(() => {
  $('input').on('keypress', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      const newTask = $(this).val();
      if (newTask) {
        var li = $("<li><input type='checkbox' id='newtasklist' class='right-margin' <label>" + newTask + "</label> <button type='button' class='deletetask'></button> <button type='button' class='addtocalendar'></button> </li>");
        $('#tasksUL').append(li);
        $(this).val("");
      }
    }
  });
  $('body').on('click', ':checkbox', function(e) {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('selected');
  });
  $(document).on("click", ".deletetask", function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
  });
});
```

```css
.selected {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.right-margin {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

input[id="newtasklist"] {
  background: url('taskchecked.png');
  background-size: 100%;
}

.deletetask {
  background: url('delete.png') no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="newtask" value="" spellcheck="false" placeholder="New Task" id="newtask">
<ul id="tasksUL">
  <li><input type="checkbox" id="newtaskitem" class="right-margin"><label>test</label> <button type="button" class="deletetask"></button></li>
</ul>
```

At the moment, there are no buttons showing next to each of the individual list items. How can I make it so the delete buttons show the the right of each list item?

Comment: You haven't put a title of button in your code. Try to put Title of button like <button>Title of Button</button> so you can find that your button is exact in position as you expect. in your case <button type="button" class="deletetask">DELETE</button>

Comment: Make the parent position:relative; (li) then the button as position:absolute;